# Run a docker container after running docker import

Tags: docker

I'm trying to test a workflow where I export a docker container and then import it onto another system. For the test, I'm working just on my system. I created a .tar file from a container that I had created, and then deleted all containers / volumes on my system.

Then, I imported the .tar file back into docker, like so:

```
> docker import c:/max_docker/vol_backup.tar

sha256:39da6ef6400fed7b4bbf153bf9525c4f4094a8e5d465e1736a070769957a3d37
```

I verified the image got loaded correctly...

```
> docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                            <none>              39da6ef6400f        30 seconds ago      11.8GB
ubuntu                            latest              74435f89ab78        39 hours ago        73.9MB
overv/openstreetmap-tile-server   latest              a964a65d28d1        2 weeks ago         3.21GB
```

Then, I tried to create a container from my image:

```
> docker run -v /var/lib/postgresql/12/main --name dbstore2 39da6ef6400f
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The syntax of my command appears to be incorrect, but I'm not having much luck figuring out why from the Docker docs or from SO. Can I not run an image just by supplying the image id?

---

**EDIT:**

To be clear, my entire goal was to move a volume of data from one system to another. I couldn't figure out how to locate the volume (I'm on Windows 10) or how to export the volume (Docker doesn't appear to support this) so I thought I'd try putting the volume's data into a container, and then exporting that container onto a different system.

Comment: Doesn't the `-v` flag require two arguments separated by a `;`?

Comment: This isn't a standard Docker workflow.  Typically you'd describe your image setup in a Dockerfile, `docker build` an image out of it, and `docker run` containers from that; if you need to change the image setup, update the Dockerfile and delete and recreate the existing container.  I don't think I've ever used `docker import`; what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: (Also note that none of the imperative Docker commands will preserve data in volumes attached to containers: you can't commit or export a database container with its data.  Move the data separately to the new system, then run a new container pointing at it.)

Answer (score 2):

The `CMD` of your image has been lost, so Docker doesn't know what default command to start in the container. That's a known limitation of an exported image, which does not preserve metadata. Try using `docker save` instead of `export`. Or use the `--change` flag on your `docker import` to add back the `CMD` you set for your original image.

Answer (score 0):

`docker export` and `docker import` only work with the filesystem of your image: they are not aware of your `CMD` nor `ENTRYPOINT`, and as such an imported will have both unset.

You can check that they have no values set for `Cmd` or `Entrypoint` with `docker image inspect`:

```
$ docker image inspect
...
"Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
...
```

If you really need to save a container as an image, preserving also the configuration, you should use `docker commit` to turn the container into an image, then `docker save` to save the image to a file. If you can work only with images though, you should use `docker save` without having to commit the container.